# Shift/reduce error in parsing a data format containing slash-separated fields that end in a double slash

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am parsing a series of lines, where each line contains a number of fields. The fields are separated by slash. The final line ends with two slashes. Several fields at the end of each line are optional; when omitted, the corresponding slashes are likewise omitted. I am getting shift/reduce conflicts.

I created a Minimal Reproducible Example to illustrate. There is just one line, containing two fields, the second field is optional, the line ends in two slashes. Here are two sample inputs:

```
/1/2//

/1//
```

Below is my lexer and parser. Bison raises a shift/reduce error message. I think that I know why Bison raises a shift/reduce error: after parsing the first field (e.g., after parsing "1") it encounters a slash, Bison doesn't know whether to reduce (there's only one field) or to shift (there's an upcoming second field). So there is an ambiguity and hence the shift/reduce error. Is that correct? Is there a way to modify the grammar so that there isn't an ambiguity?

Here is my .l file:

```
%{
#include "helloworld.tab.h"
%}

%%
"/"             { return yytext[0]; }
[ ]+
[0-9]+          { return(DGT); }
%%
int yywrap(){ return 1;}
```

Here is my .y file:

```
int yylex(void);
extern FILE *yyin;
void yyerror(const char* msg);
%}

%token DGT

%%
test: row '/' '/' 
 ;
 
row: '/' DGT '/' DGT        
 | '/' DGT                   
 ;
%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    
    yyparse();
    
    fclose(yyin);
    
    return 0;
}

void yyerror(const char *msg)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
}
```

Comment: I think I would treat // as a single separate token. You need `row: /*empty*/ | row '/' DGT  ;` surely? or if there must be at least one field `row : '/' DGT | row '/' DGT ;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution, which is actually similar to the more general grammar you started with:

```
/* This extra production allows the parser to recognise multiple lines
 * It requires that your lexer returns `'\n'` when it reads one.
 */
file  : %empty | file line '\n'
line  : fields '/' '/'
fields: %empty | fields field
field : '/' DGT
```

The big difference here is that the parser always makes `fields` out of the fields seen up to that point, which means that there is no confusion between the `/` which starts a field and the `/` which starts the end of line indicator.

Of course, the end of line indicator is a little redundant in this case because the grammar also happens to insist that the line be terminated with a newline. Putting that in a separate production was a bit arbitrary, but it seemed more likely to correspond with your real problem.

Comment: Hello @rici When I run your solution (which, by the way, is great) I get an error: invalid directive '%error'. When I replace %error with space, it works fine. Thoughts about %error?

Comment: @RogerCostello: there is no `%error` in my answer. `%error` would certainly be an error. I use `%empty`; if you copied that correctly and you get an error, I can only recommend that you upgrade to a version of bison released in the last decade. (Also, stop using  `-y`, if you are.) If you really don't want to upgrade, you can just leave out `%empty`; it's only function is to make empty rules visible.

Comment: Hello again @rici Okay, I downloaded the latest version of win flex-bison (https://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/) and bison reports this error when I run in on your solution: invalid directive: '%empty' Perhaps %empty is not available in the windows version of flex-bison? (In my previous comment I meant to say %empty but it somehow came out as %error)

Comment: @roger: see the **Updates** on that page for Bison 3 downloads. Bison 2.7 is indeed old and does not support lots of things, including `%empty`.

Comment: Ah! @rici you are right! I downloaded Bison 3 and now %empty works great. Thank you!